# Accessing any php hosted page gives page ok

Tags: php

I cannot access my site as mydomain.com/abc.php  it alwayz gives me page ok. Please Help
The page only consists of an echo statement.I have copied it to root folder of my hosted website.

Comment: Please add the code. And by page ok, you mean an HTTP 200 OK response right?

Comment: please put some code or error message here.

Answer (score 2):

The godaddy's "pageok" error page is a DNS issue -- at least for the case I have gone through. Unfortunately, there is no article from godaddy.

First, check your hosting account for the server ip.
Next, do a traceroute to your domain. You can use http://www.network-tools.com for this.
Third, if the server ip and the traceroute yield differently, update your DNS entry and use the server ip from your hosting account information.
Lastly, wait for the DNS to propagate which may take some time. You can always check back with the traceroute to make sure they are the same.

This is done automatically if the DNs is registered on GoDaddy. If not, you'll have to do it manually.

Hope it helps anyone finding it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the php file in the folder public_html
This should work

Answer (score 0):

This error is a Godaddy error that generally means your site is not configured at the hosting account it's currently pointed at. If you've just made changes to your  hosting or DNS, I recommend simply waiting for everything to propagate.

If it's been more than 48 hours, I would verify that your hosting is set up with your domain, and if it is, give Godaddy support a call. They may have something misconfigured on their end.

I also have a full write-up of the [pageok error on my site](https://pagecrafter.com/pageok-hosting-error-with-godaddy/).

Answer (score 0):

In GoDaddy, make sure that all of your files exist in the public_html folder.

Another thing to make sure is that your file abc.php contains the extension .php instead of just being saved as "abc".